# Using then() on a promise returned by fetch returns undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jwt, fetch

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/callicoder/spring-security-react-ant-design-polls-app

I already have a working backend that generates the JWT, and also the API returns the current user's details in http://localhost:8080/api/user/me with the `GET` method. All good on the back (tested with Postman).

But I have a problem when I try to load the current user from the API to the state of my `App` component. The idea is to create a route to the `Login` component and pass it a reference to the `handleLogin` method, which executes `getCurrentUser()` and redirects to the main page.

All of this is done via imports of a file called `APIUtils` that has methods to interact with the API. In particular, it has a generic `request()` method, that returns a promise using fetch, and receives the request's parameters. The problem is I can't get the response of the promise returned by the `APIUtils/request()` method. It says it's undefined.

**App.js**

```js
//imports
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    currentUser: null
  }

  loadCurrentUser = () => {
    // getCurrentUser is imported from APIUtils/index.js
    getCurrentUser()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: response
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }

  handleLogin = () => {
        this.loadCurrentUser();
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCurrentUser();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/login" 
          render={
            (props) => <Login onLogin={this.handleLogin} {...props} />
        }/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

**APIUtils/index.js**

```js
const request = (options) => {
    const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })

    if(localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN))
    }

    const defaults = { headers: headers };
    options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);

    return fetch(options.url, options)
    .then(response => {
        response.json().then(json => {
            if(!response.ok) {
                return Promise.reject(json);
            }
            return json;
        })}
    );
}

// expects loginRequest = { email: 'something', password: 'something' }
export const login = (loginRequest) => {
    return request({
            url: API_BASE_URL + "/auth/signin",
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(loginRequest)
    });
}

export const getCurrentUser = () => {
    if(!localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
        return Promise.reject("No access token set.");
    }
    return request({
            url: API_BASE_URL + "/user/me",
            method: 'GET'
    });
}
```

**Login.js**

```js
class Login extends Component {

    state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const loginRequest = Object.assign({}, this.state);

        login(loginRequest)
            .then(response => {
                localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.accessToken);
                this.props.onLogin();
            }).catch(error => {
                if(error.status === 401) {
                    console.log('Your Username or Password is incorrect. Please try again!');
                } else {
                    console.log('Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again!');                                         
                }
            });
    }

  render () {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
        /* 
        * form using onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        * inputs using value={this.state.email} and onChange={this.handleChange}
        * button of type="submit"
        */
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    } 
}
export default Login;
```

With this, after I log in and I load the landing page, via console I checked and I have the token in the local storage, also the request() method in APIUtils returns a response with URL: http://localhost:8080/api/user/me, and returns the `json` promise that's in the code, which is something like this:

```
{
  "id": 23,
  "name": "john",
  "email": "new@mail.com"
}
```

But when I try to access the response from getCurrentUser() in App.js using then(), it response is undefined, so I can't set it to the state.

Comment: If `request` returns a call to `fetch` then it should be returning a `Promise` not `undefined`.

Comment: When I console.log(response) from request(), it shows this: `Response { body: ReadeableStream { locked: true }, headers: Headers {}, type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/me", ... }`  but I don't know if I'm using then() on the return fetch() or the return inside fetch, where it returns the json response variable.

Comment: Can I suggest that the confusion you are encountering here - is why you should use `async/await`

Comment: I was reading earlier about async/await, but I really don't have the time to fully understand it. My knowledge of javascript is not so good, I can get most things that I need done, but at this moment I can't take the time to learn a new concept and try it inside my project. I will do it in the future though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning the result of `fetch()`:

```
return fetch(options.url, options)
    .then(response => { // you forgot that this is also a function
        return response.json().then(json => { // <--- missing return!!
            if(!response.ok) {
                return Promise.reject(json);
            }
            return json;
        })}
    );
```

I can understand why you may have missed it. It's fairly easy to miss. Which is why you should use the main feature of Promises - the reason they were invented - promise chaining:

```
let ok = null;
return fetch(options.url, options)
    .then(response => {
        ok = response.ok;
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => {
        if (!ok) {
            return Promise.reject(json);
        }
        return json;
    });
```

It's easier to spot a missing return this way because you can easily check that each `then` block has a `return` statment.

Comment: it says response is undefined, I think because it's not visible from the second then(). Maybe I should put the if statement in the first then() and reject(response) instead of reject(json).

Comment: Yeah. Didn't notice that. It takes a bit of creative coding to fix it

Comment: I was doing something similar to what you did. Now it works. Thanks!